# `MouseMove A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight` not working as expected

Tags: screen, autohotkey, cursor-position, mouse-cursor

Quote from [the documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Screen):

> `A_ScreenWidth`, `A_ScreenHeight`: The width and height of the primary monitor, in pixels (e.g. 1024 and 768).

I expected `MouseMove A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight` to move the cursor tip at the right bottom of the screen, for example, if the screen's resolution is 1920 x 1080, then the cursor tip should be moved to `(1920, 1080)`, but in reality, the cursor tip was moved to `(1912, 1072)`.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the coordinate mode using [`CoordMode`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm) before using [`MouseMove`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseMove.htm):

```
CoordMode Mouse

MouseMove A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight
```